# Adding an entity during @EntityListeners execution to outer transaction

Tags: spring, jpa, eclipselink

I have added an entity listener by annotating with

```
@EntityListeners
```

The call for adding or updating this entity is wrapped inside a big transaction that contains also some other changes.

In order to trigger the listener directly after the entity was created, I flush my changes directly after creating the object with

```
getEntityManager().flush()
```

The listener on this change gets triggered immediately and as expected. Inside the callback I want to add an additional operation to the transaction. But somehow, this does not work. The operations just get ignored when committing the transaction afterwards (again outside the listener).

Is there a possibility to add an operation to a transaction inside this listener, while the transaction itself was started before? Or, as a work around, is it possible to have some kind of a nested transaction that contains only the operations that are done in the listener? Using @Transactional does not work as well.

**Edit:**

added diagram to show flow
[image: flow]

When adding the code for creating the second entity at position (2), the entity is not added to the transaction. At position (1) (outside the listener), everything works.

Comment: Why not just execute it yourself if it isn't dependant on the main transaction - What do you want to happen if the main transaction rolls back?

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Chris. Actually, it depends on the main transaction. So if a rollback of the main transaction happens, then the changes of the listener should also roll back.

Comment: Then that rules out a separate transaction. You should be making these changes within your "create entity" step and not rely on listeners to create or modify 'other' entities in the graph. Otherwise, you might accomplish what you want with EclipseLink but it isn't reliable, compliant with the JPA spec, or usable on anything but prePersist. See https://www.eclipse.org/lists/eclipselink-users/msg06451.html

Comment: okay, got this. Then ill probably change my code to work outside the listeners, should be possible.

Comment: Out of interest, how would you do the changes inside a new transaction? I was not able to create a new one as the "outer" one is still not commited.

Comment: That would be a container/spring thing - you'd call into some other service that is in a different transactional scope that requires a new one.